# c1 vs c2 PR2 Filesystem Organization

Tags: ros, filesystem, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is the root cause behind [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/28897/rospack-caching-failure/). Short version: Roslaunch is not finding the right packages on c2.

The problem is that my package path included `/home/dlu/ros` which works on c1, but not on c2. The correction is that `/u/dlu/ros` works on both.

Are there any other differences between c1 and c2 in how their file systems are organized?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38038/c1-vs-c2-pr2-filesystem-organization/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pr2 filesystem overview can be found in the [PR2 Manual](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter13#Home_Directories) including discussion of home directories and unionFS setup.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1